# How do you use multiple namespaces in i18next?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, i18next

I'm just starting i18next and I'd like to create translation file for each module in my project. It seems like using namespaces would be the right way to do this. The project can create a page layout using multiple views, so I need to be able to translate strings from multiple namespaces simultaneously.

I've create a simple example that has two namespaces, but I can only get i18next to translate strings for one namespace. If I use `defaultNs: namespaces[0]` then the numbers get translated, with `defaultNs: namespaces[1]` the colors are translated, and with `defaultNs: namespaces` *nothing* is translated. But I cannot figure out how to get both namespaces to translate.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="i18next.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var language = "en";
            var namespaces = [ "numbers", "colors" ];
            var config = {
                lng: language,
                fallbackLng: "en",
                resGetPath: "namespaces/__ns__/__ns__-__lng__.json",
                ns: {
                    namespaces: namespaces,
                    defaultNs: namespaces[0]
                },
                debug: true
            };
            i18n.init( config, function onInitComplete() {
                $(".xl8").i18n();
            });

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hello, i18n!</h1>
        <ol>
            <li class="xl8" data-i18n="numbers.one">1</li>
            <li class="xl8" data-i18n="numbers.two">2</li>
            <li class="xl8" data-i18n="numbers.three">3</li>
        </ol>
        <ul>
            <li class="xl8" data-i18n="colors.red">r</li>
            <li class="xl8" data-i18n="colors.green">g</li>
            <li class="xl8" data-i18n="colors.blue">b</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this same question on github and received the following working answer from **jamuhl**:

> if a resource is not on the default namespace use:

```
    <li class="xl8" data-i18n="colors:colors.blue">b</li> --> namespace:key
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is slightly hack-ish for the use case you describe but (assuming you only want to have two namespaces active at any one time & the keys do not clash) you can do this:

```
fallbackNS: 'colors',
ns: {
    namespaces: ['colors', 'numbers'],
    defaultNs: 'numbers'
}
```

This is not really designed for your use case though - it's more designed for a situation where you want to display some translations differently based on another factor - e.g an app which displays 'Employee' for business users or 'Student' for school users - but mainly uses the same set of defaults.