# Nested namespaces in i18n

Tags: javascript, typescript, internationalization, i18next

My application is rather large, so to have a more organized translation file I want to use nested namespaces. Example:

```
{
    "contract": {
        "index": {
            "pageTitle": "Contract"
    }
}
```

The problem with this is when I'm accessing it. With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003736/how-do-you-use-multiple-namespaces-in-i18next) I found out I can access the keys inside index by using it as below:

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation('contract', { useSuspense: false });
...
t('index.pageTitle')
```

The problem is It seems rather unecessary to prefix `index.` to every key I want to access. What I would like to do is import the namespace index instead of contract, and use it as below:

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation('contract:index', { useSuspense: false });
...
t('pageTitle')
```

Which doesn't work. I tried `contract.index` as well. In the official documentation I found nothing about nesting. Is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do or will I have to stick with prexifing every key?

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/387 . The problem might be in semicolon. Maybe you need to define some extra property for separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some good time, I found something that resembles nested namespacing in i18n. Apparently, you can get a new translation object from a translation hook, as such:

```
const { t } = useTranslation('batch');
const nestedNamespace = t('id.someOtherSection', { returnObjects: true })
```

And, to access properties of `nestedNamespace`, you can call it directly, as such:

```
nestedNamespace.someTranslation -> THIS WORKS!!!
nestedNamespace('someTranslation') -> THIS WON'T WORK!
```

Answer (score 4):

[Nested namespaces are not supported](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1516).

You can decorate the `useTranslation` hook to provide this extended functionality for pages in the namespace.

```
import { useTranslation as useTranslationBase } from "react-i18next";

const useTranslation = (ns, page, props={}) => {
  const trans = useTranslationBase(ns, props);

  return {
    ...trans,
    t: (keys, options) => {
      let _keys = keys;
      if (!Array.isArray(keys)) _keys = [String(keys)];
      _keys = _keys.map(key =>`${page}.${key}`)
     return trans.t(_keys, options)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
export default function () {
  const { t } = useTranslation('contract', 'index');
  return <div>{t(["pageTitle"])}-{t("pageTitle")}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The original answers are not correct, you can actually have nesting with the [`keyPrefix`](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#optional-keyprefix-option) option.

In your case this should work:

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation('contract', { useSuspense: false, keyPrefix: 'index' });
...
t('pageTitle')
```